# Orthogonal vectors, $||\lambda a+\mu b||$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $a$ and $b$ are orthogonal, and $||a|| = ||b|| = 1$, calculate $||\lambda a+ \mu b||$.

$\langle \lambda a+ \mu b, \lambda a + \mu b \rangle = \langle \lambda a, \lambda a\rangle + 2 \langle \lambda a, \mu b\rangle + \langle \mu b, \mu b \rangle$

$\langle \lambda a, \mu b\rangle =0$

Here is where I am unsure.

$\lambda^2 \langle a,a \rangle + \mu^2 \langle b,b \rangle = \lambda^2+\mu^2$

Is this correct?

Comment: Can you please edit your question by writing the mathematical logic and steps in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)? The answer should rather be $\sqrt{\lambda^2 + \mu^2}$, but in order for us to see where your mistake on this occurs, it's much more helpful if you provide us with the work you completed.

Comment: @Decaf-Math yeah I will use math Jax I currently don’t have a full keyboard so many symbols are not possible,  but I will correct later.  Thanks forgot about the square root

Comment: Do you know the definition of inner product?

Comment: That would be true iff the vectors were orthogonal.

Comment: @WillM. Function into r, or c, for which linearity ,positive defitness and symmetry are true. .

Comment: @MichaelHoppe they are :)

Comment: @Lillys By linearity and symmetry $(\lambda a, \mu b) = \lambda \mu (a, b) = \lambda \mu 0 = 0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Given:** $a$ and $b$ are orthogonal, so $\langle a , b \rangle = \langle b , a \rangle = 0$, and $\| a \| = \| b \| = 1$, which means $\sqrt{\langle a , a \rangle }= \sqrt{ \langle b , b \rangle }= 1$.

**We want to evaluate:**

\begin{align*}
\| \lambda a + \mu b \|^2 &= \langle \lambda a + \mu b , \lambda a + \mu b \rangle \\
&=\langle \lambda a , \lambda a + \mu b \rangle + \langle \mu b , \lambda a + \mu b \rangle \\
&= \langle \lambda a , \lambda a \rangle + \langle \lambda a , \mu b \rangle + \langle \mu b , \lambda a \rangle + \langle \mu b , \mu b \rangle \\
&= \lambda\overline{\lambda} \langle a , a \rangle + \lambda\overline{\mu}\langle a , b \rangle + \mu\overline{\lambda}\langle b, a \rangle + \mu\overline{\mu}\langle b , b \rangle \\
&=\lambda\overline{\lambda}(1) + \lambda\overline{\mu}(0) + \mu\overline{\lambda}(0) + \mu\overline{\mu}(1) \\
&=\lambda\overline{\lambda} + \mu\overline{\mu},
\end{align*}
Hence,
$$\| \lambda a + \mu b \| = \sqrt{\lambda\overline{\lambda}+\mu\overline{\mu}}$$
where $\overline{\xi}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $\xi$, note if $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$ then $\overline{\xi}=\xi$.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a square: you should have $\|x\|^2 = \langle x, x\rangle$.

Comment: @B.Mehta Yes, oops! Thanks for the catch:)